# Dangers of smoking hookah

Tags: smoking, nicotine, smoke-inhalation

In my country, hookah just became insanely popular.
Government agencies alongside health organizations mobilized and started to forbid smoking under the pretense that it is as unhealthy as cigarettes, **or maybe even more unhealthy**.

But that's gonna be a lie right? No one died from hookah.
So my question is smoking hookah really unhealthy and if so, how unhealthy it is?

Comment: Inhaling smoke is unhealthy. Period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it isn't healthy.
It will not provide you vitamins, or cure you from cold.

TL;DR
But it isn't *very* unhealthy. What that means is that there are health **risks** you must take into account and decide whether it worths it. Smoking hookah can also be very beneficial in terms of the way you feel. For some people, those benefits overly exceed these on cigarettes, which is one of the reasons they quit smoking, which is a good thing, because cigarettes are more harmful than hookah, but they can also be less harmful than hookah. It depends on how much you smoke. The more you smoke the more the risk increases. People have tendency to abuse cigarettes more than hookah, partially because smoking cigarettes is easier, cheaper and more practical.

So, generally there are much more harmful chemicals in generic tobacco, but we will discuss the top 3 most hazardous of them. Videlicet:

1. [Nicotine](https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/240820.php)
2. [Tar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(tobacco_residue))
3. [Carbon monoxide (and dioxide when oxygenation)](https://www.co2meter.com/blogs/news/1209952-co-and-co2-what-s-the-difference)

### Let's start off with the nicotine.

Not all hookah is prepared with a tobacco that contains nicotine. It could still be tobacco, but wiped out tobacco, soaked in water even boiled, until its full purification. I would still not give my bets on that though as it may still contain some levels of nicotine, which immediately turns it into an unhealthier product. You can also smoke shisha gels, shisha fruits, steam stones and Hookah Creams - all of these do not contain nicotine unless explicitly added.
Although there is insufficient evidence to classify nicotine as a carcinogen, there is an ongoing debate about whether it functions as a tumor promoter. Almost all hookah tobacco (like Al. Fakher, Gazi and whatever) contain approximately .05% nicotine. If it says .5%, that is probably a typo. Nakhla shisha is the only brand that boast .5% approx.
these percentages will stay the same regardless of whether you load a 20g bowl or a 100g bowl. That means if you buy 50grammes you will be smoking 0.025mg of nicotine around 5 times. Note that this is the general content of nicotine not the actual amount, being absorbed from the organism. The smoker inhales smoke, by which the nicotine absorbs. Hookah is something to be shared with a company, so very often it is being shared from 2 to even up to 10 people, distributing the total nicotine intake, but eventually exposing all to the secondhand smoke. How much of the substance you would get is determined by variety of different factors such as how long you smoke, how much smoke you inhale, how often you inhale. Some people think that because of the huge amount of smoke the hookah produces it is by any chances loading you with much higher levels of nicotine, which is not true, because 1. 50% of the smoke being produced is actually a vegetable glycerine and 2. Because the nicotine level will not magically increase, specially for your bigger clouds. Bigger clouds only means overtoasting the tobacco, which ultimately leads to a reducing time of use. At least pleasurable time. Almost all the times bigger clouds means shorter hookah session lifespan. One hookah session can vary but people generalize it to between 45 minutes and one hour. So there is still some nicotine you will absorb, which makes it unhealthy. Lots of people smoke cigarettes for 45 minutes too, smoking much cigarettes that contain much higher density of poison.
[Nicotine leads to addiction](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2928221/). Adding good flavors only make it more charming and more addictive.

### Tar

The tar is a known carcinogen.
Sometimes, this substance is even more dangerous, because unlike the nicotine, which absorbs in your body fast, the tar does not and it produces dense accumulation over time, that kills the pulmonary tissue. It may also cause cancer. ([Support Reference](https://www.cancer.gov/publications/dictionaries/cancer-terms?cdrid=743063))
The process of purifying tobacco removes some of the tar, but not completely.
Cigarettes take advantage of some 3 centimeter filter of "foam" while the hookah gives you a few hundreds of water filtration, which "wash" the smoke itself.
And it works a-okay. As the time goes and you smoke, you can notice that the water becomes more yellowish. Some people wrongly assume that's all tar, but it is proven that it contains so much more, including molasses and solid particles /heavy metals. The water does not only filter, but it also cools down the smoke and when the smoke is cooled down, it is lighter and when it is lighter it is easier for your lungs to aspirate it.
So a good practice is to put ice in the water phial. You can also try one of those [water enhancers](https://www.hookah-shisha.com/p-18164-sultana-add-reducer-4-pack.html). Manufactures claim that it empowers the water with special molecular level filtration abilities. I haven't encounter scientific studies remotely related to this product yet, but from using it I can not tell.

### Carbon monoxide and dioxide

This is what is being produced from the process of burning. It is being released by the charcoal. When smoking cigarettes you are exposed to a direct burning of a tobacco set on fire, which gives you a lot of carbon mono and some dioxide. When you smoke hookah, the shisha does not burn. It bakes. On a temperature of anything around 100C. But, I shall tell you that, the carbon monoxide released from angry lighter coal might exceed that from cigarettes and cigs, mainly because of the duration of your drag. Carbon monoxide might be the least of your problems. It causes dizziness, caused by the blood vessels (arterial) tightening, whereat the heart rate increases to compensate the blood delivery to your brain.

---

To summerize:
Nicotine is in very low levels and density - there is a slight but existing risk of developing cancer and increase of cholesterol levels and even greater risk of addiction. Smoking inside somewhere may lead to a nicotine exposure equal to or greater than that if you were smoking, it depends on the place, its ventilation, air flow and how much people smoke.

The tar is in low levels and density, the more you smoke, the higher levels of it you accumulate. Smoking way too frequent leads to more tar being accumulated, which may damage everything between your mouth and lungs and cause cancer.

Carbon dioxide isn't risky - it WILL violate human internal processes.

**So it is unhealthy, obviously. Not so unhealthy to lead to death or cause irreversible consequences as such haven't been documented, to my knowledge.**

---

Read this:
http://www.electroniccigaretteconsumerreviews.com/how-much-nicotine-is-in-one-cigarette/

Very broad NCBI article on nicotine's effects:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4363846/

In case you need, you can find more support for all that, all over the internet. Trust only trusted articles though, because in this topic, there are a lot of disagreements, from all kind of people: concerned parents, politicians, kids, "informed" bloggers, gov agencies with an unclear amploa, critics, conspiracy diggers etc and etc

Comment: Needs clarification. CO2 or CO; i.e.: and/or both? "still contain some levels of nicotine, which immediately turns it into an unhealthier product." Up to that: That reads like this one substance is the most unhealthy part in this? "Purifying"? What to what/from what? – Looks like quite a bit of expertise, does not really answer the question marks in a straight way. (But seems to be on good way, if you address the issues mentioned and add more *references* to your assertions)

Comment: @LangLangC Marry christmas

Comment: Okay so, CO is carbon monoxide as far as I think I know and CO2 is carbon dioxide (di oxide and CO2 (notice the 2) - two molecules oxygen) and I said carbon dioxide which makes it clear that I talk about CO2. In much higher levels it could be deadly. What is healthier cannot be determined, I said it depends on the smoker and its hookah, but I would say the tar is the highest concern. Purifying, only one thing can "purify" and thats the hookah's water filtration. And when the tobacco is made, it is being soaked in water (which is some form of purification as well)

Comment: @LangLangC thanks you! Also doing some research, I've spotted several places claiming "CO is deadlier" I don't know why, but CO poisoning seems more a general case

Comment: But yes, thanks for pointing my attention there. It seems that my not nativeness to the language creates some gaps. Yes, CO is indeed being released from smoking.

Comment: As I said: CO blocks the red cells from working in small concentrations (has high affinity). –  "Purification": leaching tobacco in water before and water-filtering the smoke need separation. Tobacco just cut from the plant is "pure", cured only with time is also, cured with honey or sauces it is not anymore, although often found more 'smokable' by users. Shisha tobacco is often heavily sauced and altered from what the plant delivers.

Comment: @LangLangC The process of creating shisha tobacco requires the water bath before anything else is added up, to reduce harsher smell and extract some of the nicotine, tar and probably other chemicals. Then a molasses and honey is added. During water filtration at some time, the smoke directly exposed to water serves as a cigarette filter, except more efficient

Comment: The molasses is made up from boiling sugar canes (or beet and even fruits) then mixing it with ashes for hardening. That thing bakes too and release chemicals too and washes too. Honey is probably healthier, not sure, just a guess)

Comment: AFAIK this watering is not "required", but this process enhances some pyrolisation qualities, taste and anything added then increases tar (when burned). But: The pyrolisation itself determines most characteristics of the smoke. Additives making it more enjoyable might also increase health detriments by animating to inhale deeper/longer.

Comment: @LangLangC This is both true and not true. Watering can also increase tobacco's humidity, which provokes lesser smoke production in the beginning. It is not "required", but most shisha brands do that anyway. Tangiers, nakhla may not, I can say that because their shisha makes a lot of buzz. A buzz compared that to a medwakh pipe!

Comment: The "water as an efficient filter", your numbers (percentages) smoke constituents compared to cigs, actual smoking habits observed need references (look again on [meta](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/783/quality-of-references) for inspiration on that)

Comment: @LangLangC It is being added vegetable glycerine, which could be dangerous as it evaporates and can condensate in the lungs, but not really a serious health concern. And then there are the natural and/or artificial flavors. Artificial flavors like "LorAnn" are made to be heat-resistant and safe for consumption. For smoking them, they are just like the glycerine except that with some flavoring, no one really knows a lot about. The description on them is not really "descriptive" or so to say

Comment: All excellent knowledge. Please re-read my last comment about refs and add all that and what you wrote in comments into the answer. On your way to a very nice answer. – Once you've done that, delete the redundant comments (we overdid that a bit…)

Comment: @LangLangC Done with the references. The answer is with a bit of verbatim and not direct quotes and uncaused read, because I rely on my knowledge, which is 100% influenced from a complex of powerful and trusted sources of information of such and personal experience too. I can add more references if needed :) I can also add some ugly picture of cancer to disgust smokers